# ¿Existen patrones de consulta en SQL?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, patrones-de-diseño

Es decir, situaciones, escenarios o tipos de consulta conocidos a los que típicamente se les da una solución (la consulta) también conocida en base a la experiencia.

Ayudaría tener un catálogo de estos patrones para identificarlos y aplicar la solución en lugar de reinventar la rueda cada vez. Para esto son los patrones.

Por ejemplo: división relacional, aunque se trate de una operación de conjuntos del álgebra relacional, se podría considerar como un patrón, con un escenario típico y una solución (forma de generar la consulta) o varias.

En otra ocasión preguntaré por los antipatrones :)

Comment: Tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones lo que generaría su cierre.

Comment: no. porque cada base de datos es diferente... no hay patrones..

Comment: Dudo mucho que exista algo así 1)  SQL Ansi no existe como lenguaje, más bien hay distintas y variadas implementaciones 2) Conceptualmente siempre es un único problema a resolver.

Comment: Hay formas "adecuadas" de resolver ciertas situaciones, pero no son estándar porque cada DBMS resuelve, optimiza y ejecuta las consultas de forma diferente.

Comment: @Bicho, no es una pregunta basada en opiniones, estoy preguntando algo concreto que se puede responder sí o no con su explicación.

Comment: @gbianchi los patrones no tienen que ver con plataformas específicas, sea lenguajes de programación o SGBD en este caso.

Comment: En este caso si.. porque la base de datos no funciona como un lenguaje.. dame un rato y te armo un ejemplo clarisimo de porque un patron no sirve para nada en una db

Answer (score 1):

Tal como menciona gbianchi, también creo que cada base de datos es diferente y se diseña según las necesidades de cada proyecto.

Sin embargo, tras una búsqueda rápida, econtré que los expertos de Percona han hecho una presentación que cubre exactamente tu duda. Te dejo el link de Slideshare.

https://es.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-query-patterns-optimized

En el slide 95 viene precisamente el ejemplo de la división relacional.

El autor de la presentación hizo un libro sobre anti-patrones en SQL, titulado "SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming"

Comment: esto está acoplado a MySQL

Comment: Y no es una optimizacion de patrones.. es simplemente una explicacion de como mejorar querys.. no hay patrones.. que pasa si no puedo crear un indice? que pasa si mi indice es mas lento que mi full scan??? no hay patrones, porque simplemente no hay reglas a seguir...

Comment: Entiendo, pero para los menos experimentados puede no ser tan obvio. En la presentación se menciona incluso el caso de almacenar tags separados por coma en una columna varchar, una mala práctica que es desafortunadamente común en el entorno profesional.

Comment: Debería quedar el contenido aquí no?, que pasa si deciden remover la presentación

Comment: De acuerdo, acepto sugerencias/ediciones, BetaM

Comment: Como digo en los comentarios de la pregunta: los patrones no tienen que ver con plataformas o herramientas específicas, dan soluciones generales que luego se implementan en cada entorno en particular (lenguaje, sgbd... ). Al parecer en ese enlace que compartes han identificado unos pocos patrones pero yo pensaba que habría un catálogo mas extenso. Probablemente esté tratado en algún buen libro de SQL.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**

El único patrón que tiene una base de datos, es llevar todas las tablas a 3FN (y sin embargo, hasta esto es con un * gigante).

### **Explicación.**

Ninguna base de datos, asegura nada de nada. No aseguran como estan guardados los datos, no aseguran como estan guardados los indices, no aseguran como van a ejecutar una consulta, ni siquiera aseguran que la consulta se va a ejecutar siempre de la misma manera.

Supongamos que tenemos un patrón para ejecutar una query, llamémoslo patrón A.

En dicho patrón, se supone que la tabla tiene que tener siempre la misma forma, estar guardada de la misma forma, y tener los índices del mismo tipo guardados de la misma forma.

Pues, dichas cosas no pasan en ninguna base de datos.

Aunque nuestro patrón A funcione para alguna base de datos, ese mismo patrón falla miserablemente para otra base de datos.

Y esto pasa, porque en la ejecución de un query influyen muchos factores, como por ejemplo: ¿cómo guardo la base de datos los datos?, ¿los tiene secuencial o en archivos separados?, ¿los tiene de forma de poder acceder a todos juntos o tiene que acceder de a uno?, ¿tiene algun índice que la haga acceder mas rápido?, ¿accede realmente mas rápido por el índice o accede más rápido a los datos?, ¿qué le cuesta menos?, si tiene que traer todos los registros del índice, ¿le sirve realmente entrar por índice?

¿Cuál sería un patrón?, ¿una consulta estandard? pero para eso, deberíamos necesitar una base de datos estandard.. y aunque hay bases de datos parecidas, no necesariamente son iguales y no alcanzan para generar un patrón.

Podriamos decir que el modelo de facturas (que en general es una cabecera y otra tabla que tiene los items) seria un patrón... pero eso siempre y cuando por ejemplo, tu negocio no sea un item por factura, donde el patrón, se cae a pedazos...

Y adelantandome.. un anti patrón seria no tener tus tablas en 3FN (y otra vez, con un gran asterisco)...

### GRAN ASTERISCO

Todo esto de normalizar las tablas, vale, pero no para bases de datos que sean un Datawarehouse.. en esas bases de datos, se suelen violar todas las normas de normalizacion en favor de generar consultas mucho mas rápidas.....

Comment: Sospecho que no has entendido la pregunta, o tienes otro concepto de "patrón" en ingeniería (en general), y mas concretamente en software (libro del GoF). Hablamos de SQL y de BBDDRR y todos los SGBDR devuelven el mismo conjunto de tuplas para la misma consulta sobre los mismos datos, independientemente de la gestión y detalles sintácticos de la consulta. E incluso el patrón puede dar varias soluciones o pistas para según qué caso (rendimiento según condiciones, p.ej.). La prueba de lo que digo es la respuesta de Baruch: los expertos de Percona sí han identificado patrones de consulta SQL.

Comment: @AntonioSánchez si para vos esos son patrones, perfecto. Pero te vuelvo a repetir. Escribir los querys de esa forma, porque parece lo mejor, no tiene nada que ver con un patron para base de datos. o sea, son metodos para escribir la consulta. Pero ahi nadie esta asegurando que funciona en cualquier base de datos. ninguna de esas querys.. solo hicieron un bechmark de varias soluciones. Lo volvi a ver por si se me habia escapado algo. Si vos pensas que hay formas de escribir los querys que sirvan para cualquier base de datos, sin importar la misma, buenisimo.

Comment: "no tiene nada que ver con un patron para base de datos. o sea, son metodos para escribir la consulta". Es lo que estoy preguntando: patrones de consulta SQL, no patrones de bases de datos. Cuestión aparte que el patrón que sea tenga como requisito una determinada normalización en la BDD, o cualquier otro requisito.